# LibraryFunctionLoad with Cool Prop documentation

Tags: interoperability, chemistry, librarylink

I use the following command

```
Rhol = LibraryFunctionLoad["CoolProp", 
   "PropsSI", {UTF8String, UTF8String, Real, UTF8String, Real, 
    UTF8String}, Real];Subscript[T, 0]=330;
```

to obtain fluid/vapor properties:

```
(*rho*)Subscript[ρ, l] = 
 Rhol["D", "T", Subscript[T, 0], "Q", 0, "Water"]
(*saturation pressure*)Subscript[p, 0] = 
 Rhol["P", "T", Subscript[T, 0], "Q", 1, "Water"]
(*kinematic viscosity*)Subscript[v, e] = 
 Rhol["V", "T", Subscript[T, 0], "Q", 0, "Water"]/Subscript[ρ, l]
```

With `"Water"`, everything is OK, but for example `"Acetone"` displays viscosity as an infinity sign.

Does anyone have the same problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Be aware that because most people don't have [CoolProp](http://www.coolprop.org) readily installed, it might take a while for your question to get answered.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the *Mathematica* wrappers don't expose any error handling and so this is all you get:

```
In[7]:= pathToCoolProp = 
  "/Users/jasonb/WolframWorkspaces/CoolProp/build/libCoolProp.dylib";

In[8]:= PropsSI = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[pathToCoolProp, 
   "PropsSI", {"UTF8String", "UTF8String", Real, "UTF8String", Real, 
    "UTF8String"}, Real];

In[9]:= PropsSI["V", "T", 300., "Q", 0., "Acetone"]

Out[9]= \[Infinity]
```

But if you use python you get a better message:

[image]

It would be interesting to modify the wrapper code to catch errors and return them in a meaningful way, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Wrapping [this line](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/blob/master/wrappers/Mathematica/CoolPropMathematica.cpp#L42) in a try-catch block doesn't do anything.